# npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded - Trying to install webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install, webpack-dev-server

I have been on this for the past 24hrs, I am trying to install `webpack` via `npm` with this command.

> $ npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev

and it has been a total disaster, I have tried lot of things people said online but nothing works at all.

I have tried to downgrade and upgrade my node and npm version but right now i am using the latest version.
I have also tried to run the `npm cache clear --force` and still nothing great happened.

Please if you know any fix, let me know or if you know any other way. Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion... Have you considered using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) instead? I experienced a lot of issues with npm as of node 10 / npm 6.

Comment: I used yarn but it is dependent on NPM so same error, I solved it tho

Comment: npm i -D webpack gives me the max call stack error issue ? any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder called .nmprc, I can not remember where it is located on windows but you should delete the folder and you are good to go!

Comment: It's a file (not a directory) called `.npmrc` and deleting it is not a magical fix. This is a bug that needs to be fixed in npm because authentication information is stored in this file and you cannot always build without this information.